# How can I add a Document Map to an RDLC (aka SSRS) report in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, report, rdlc, rdl

Perhaps I am missing something obvious, but I cannot find a way to add a Document Map to an RDLC file from within Visual Studio 2010 (or the stand-alone "Report Builder 2.0" for that matter).

I previous versions, such as 2005 and 2008, this was a simple matter of adding a document map label to a report item. But the property "Document Map Label" is no longer present.

Furthermore, I can't find a way to add a bookmark either.

If anyone can shed some light on this, that would be great!!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly which version you are referring to. Visual Studio 2010 does not support Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) If you install BIDS from the SQL Server 2008 R2 disk it will install the shell of Visual Studio 2008. If you already have Visual Studio 2010, installing BIDS will still install the 2008 shell of visual studio and will load that if you try to make BI projects. If you install it from SQL Server 2012 it will install the SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT), which uses the Visual Studio 2010 Shell. I suppose that's the version you mean.

I've checked my version of BIDS from SQL Server 2008R2 and all the objects added to a report do have the DocumentMapLabel property. I've also just checked my SSDT from SQL 2012 and the property is still there. Select an object on the report and look in the properties window under "Other".

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, Davos. Actually, I wasn't referring to BIDS at all. VS2010 includes a built-in Report Designer (for RLDCs). It's also possible to install a stand-alone report designer called "Report Builder 2.0", but the functionality is pretty much identical to VS2010. Neither of these requires SQL Server.

Comment: But you pointed out the thing I was missing, that the DocumentMapLabel property was indeed there. I thought it wasn't because I was looking for it in the right-click report item properties window (not in the property-grid where you highlighted it). Anyway, thanks for pointing it out. Sorry for the delay in accepting your answer. I was on hiatus. :)